# Data recovery for pulling out all data, and software to find types of content

Tags: data-recovery

I am looking to do data recovery on disk drives and memory cards. For this I want a device or type of software which allows me to pull out the following data:

- Allocated space
- Unallocated space
- Slack space
- Bad blocks

I also need a software which aids in identifying types of content discovered in fully or partially discovered data.

I would like to have as much freedom when reading the disk drives as possible, such as retrying bad block reading or forcing certain operations on the disk. I am unsure if this requires a separate disk controller to be plugged onto the drives?

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: This might be better suited on SuperUser as it doesn't really pertain to security in it's current form.

Comment: Yeah, whilst the intent falls under forensics, it's basically a data recovery question. However, I don't think a migrate would work, since I'm sure someone's asked this before on SU. I'll flag for a mod and see what they say.

Comment: Definitively forensics work I have in mind here, however I see the possible migration issue.

Comment: [su] or [security.se], this question primarily appears to be a "product recommendation" request, which is generally off-topic on SE.

Comment: @Karrax what Iszi said. You should know better ;)

Comment: hehe, Im sorry! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty data recovery for Linux often involves

- dd for disk imaging.
- ddrescue if you find you have to deal with bad sectors.  May not be optimized for flash memory (i.e. sd card/usb stick etc) though.
- [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) for scanning raw disk images for various data formats (maybe copy the image and zero out the known files, so you only find deleted ones?).
- testdisk looks for entire deleted partitions (same source as photorec)

"file" is occasionally useful, if you think you have a valid file but aren't sure what type of application to try reading it with.  Much of the time I'm using it for some other purpose - though I guess my frequent `file -s /dev/sda1` counts if you stretch it a bit.

There are definitely more specific, professional solutions though.  I believe some software contains hashes of many known files.  That would be useful for "needle in a haystack" problems - someone could have hidden files on a computer under the Windows directory, for example.